# Use specific version of http in tcl

Tags: http, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am currently developing on Ubuntu 20.04. I am using the current latest version of tcl that is shipped with http version 2.9.1. However I need to use a specific version of http package i.e 2.8.9. When I use the directive:

```
package require http -exact 2.8.9
```

I get an error that it couldnt find the package http 2.8.9. Is there some way to download that specific http package and then use it in my script. Or is there a way to downgrade tcl to an earlier version. Or download an earlier version of tcl and then specify which version to use.

Comment: Why are you wanting to use that specific version?

Comment: I am currently extending an application that is written in that specific version and seems to be not working with the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab it from the github mirror: https://github.com/tcltk/tcl/blob/core-8-6-6/library/http/http.tcl

1. Save that version as `http.tcl` in a directory, say `/path/to/my/http`
2. `cd /path/to/my/http`
3. `echo "pkg_mkIndex ." | tclsh`

Then, in your tcl script:

```
lappend auto_path /path/to/my/http
package require -exact http 2.8.9
```

You can also `lappend auto_path /path/to/my` -- the package loader looks in directories in $auto_path, and also immediate subdirectories of those directories, to find the pkgIndex.tcl files. Using `/path/to/my` allows you to have other custom package directories under that parent directory

Comment: The definitive version is found at https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/dir?ci=core-8-6-6&name=library/http (fossil links are a bit different to github links)